How to round a number to the next number due to number of decimal?
Here's my attempted result:
396.6 -> 400
39.66 -> 40
3.96 -> 4
0.396 -> 0.4

How can I do this in C#? Here's my attempt:
public static double CeilToNextSameDecimal(double number)
{
    int decimalPlaces = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits((decimal)number)[3])[2];
    double factor = Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return Math.Ceiling(number * factor) / factor;
}

But give to me wrong results (i.e. the same input):
396.6
39.66
3.966
0.3966


So you want to round up to a single non-zero decimal digit?  In IEEE754 FP you should get this by default if you specify the print format correctly. To do it manually convert to a string and then apply the rules as described at rounding methods - round half to even also called bankers rounding. Other rounding rules are available (lots of them).

Your method of querying the decimal number gets you the number of decimals. However, what we are interested is the number of digits before decimals.
So what we are looking for is something like the following, which is the cousin of your attempt.
public static double CeilToNextSameDecimal(double number)
{
    var digitsBeforeDecimals = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(number));
    double factor = Math.Pow(10, digitsBeforeDecimals - 1);
    return Math.Ceiling(number / factor) * factor;
}

Results in
120.6 -> 200
39.66 -> 40
3.966 -> 4
0.01 -> 0.01


Here is my attempt:
var round = Math.Ceiling(input / 10);
var result = input < 1 ?                  
        (Math.Ceiling((input * 10)) / 10) :  
            round < 10   
            ? Math.Ceiling((input /10) * 10) 
            : round * 10;

.Net fiddle

Explanation:
For numbers less than 1:

Multiply the number by 10 and then use Math.Ceil() to convert the number to a higher end, then divide it.

For rest:

Check Math.Ceil() value first, if it is less than 10, then Math.Ceiling((input /10) * 10) otherwise Math.Ceiling(input / 10) * 10

